# Memory Error using predict_generator and VGG16

Tags: python, memory, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to apply transfer learning on my own dataset, which exists out of 33.000 training images (1,4GB in total). I am running into memory errors when  making my predictions using the predict_generator in Keras (2.2.0). When looking at my task manager I can see the memory slowly working up to the max VRAM of 5GB of my Tesla K80 (1GPU). I am using the following code:

```
#Train
print('train dataset:')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False)

num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)
nb_train_samples = len(train_generator.filenames)
predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(nb_train_samples / batch_size))
VGG16_bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(train_generator, predict_size_train, verbose=1)
np.save('XVGG16_bottleneck_features_train.npy', VGG16_bottleneck_features_train)
```

I have tried many things but I cannot seem to make it work for me. I have read many solutions that suggested the use of batches, but I thought that my predict_generator was already receiving the data in batch form? Is there sombody here that can verify that that this is not going to work for my system or is there another solution possible?

Answer (score 0):

The memory required for inference scales with the number of images you try to pass through the network simultaneously, i.e., the batch size. You can try smaller batch sizes until it runs. The smaller the batch size, the more batches the generator will need to yield to pass over the entire dataset (`predict_size_train` in your code).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have lowered my batch size up to 2, which now allows me to get it working for 15.000 images (30 classes) , but 30.000 still seems too much. Any idea if that is just too much?

Comment: In that case, you are probably running out of RAM when trying to hold all the predictions in memory before storing them. You could try yielding from the generator, using `predict_on_batch` instead and storing your files in batches instead of one large np file.